# What does Change Destination do for a branch in SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am puzzling over the meaning of "Change Destination" in the following screen in SourceTree [image: here]

I expect that "Change Destination" is not a git command since the word "destination" does not appear in the [Git Glossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_ref)

When I click the "change destination" button the top "master" icon turns into a combo box containing branch names.

If I select an old branch then a list of commits appears